# How to see if box top price has touched after plotting on the chart

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

```
Created a new box on chart which passes criteria wick of candle 70 percent now if price came into the box after I drawn box just have to delete box. please help needed    
**OBS = box.new(left=bar_index-1,top=low[n],right =bar_index+100 ,bottom=high[n],border_color =color.black,border_width = 1,bgcolor = color.rgb(104, 204, 174, 51),extend = extend.right )
    float box_top = box.get_top(OBS)
    if box_top<low
       box.delete(box.delete(OBS))**
```

above is the code for the box creation which I want to delete later.How to delete the box if price came in the range again

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your box with the `var` keyword. Then use the `box.get_top()` and `box.get_bottom()` functions to see if price has tocuhed it.

```
box_high = box.get_top(OBS)
box_low = box.get_bottom(OBS)
low_breach_check = (open < box_low) and (high >= box_low)
high_breach_check = (open > box_high) and (low <= box_high)

if (low_breach_check or high_breach_check)
    box.delete(OBS)
```